# Android studio stuck at around 80% loading on osx Big Sur

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

After upgrading my iMac to Big Sur,downloaded and installed Android Studio 4.1.1, built on Nov 4. After installation, started Android Studio. It is stuck on Splashscreen progress bar at the bottom showing around 80%. Has anyone seen this? Any pointers how to fix this?

## The log shows some issue with FUCounterUsageLogger:

2020-11-15 07:51:21,517 [  98434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
2020-11-15 07:51:21,517 [  98434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2020-11-15 07:51:21,517 [  98434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X
2020-11-15 07:51:21,517 [  98434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
2020-11-15 07:51:21,517 [  98434]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
at com.intellij.featureStatistics.fusCollectors.LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.onError(LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.java:123)
at com.intellij.diagnostic.DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.canHandle(DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.java:62)
at com.intellij.diagnostic.DialogAppender.appendToLoggers(DialogAppender.java:85)

Comment: yes i have same problem, i think any window you open in android Studio make it stuck.

for example tip of a day will make your android studio stuck, opining settings, git commit and push window.

Answer (score 1):

Could not get it working. Went back to previous release could not get it working. However later release, 4.2 preview, works!

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue on an old Mojave machine. 4.2 preview is working for me; thanks!